# How can I cache a database query with "IN" operator?

Tags: spring, caching

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Cache. I have a method that, given a list of ids, returns a list of `Food` that match with those ids:

```
public List<Food> get(List<Integer> ids) {
    return "select * from FOOD where FOOD_ID in ids"; // << pseudo-code
}
```

I want to cache the results by id. Imagine that I do:

```
List<Food> foods = get(asList(1, 5, 7));
```

and then:

```
List<Food> foods = get(asList(1, 5));
```

I want to `Food` with id 1 and `Food` with id 5 to be retrieved from cache. Is it possible?

I know I can do a method like:

```
@Cacheable(key = "id")
public Food getById(id){
    ...
}
```

and iterate the ids list and call it each time, but in that case I don't take advantage of `IN` SQL operator, right? Thanks.

Comment: just do 

`return ids.stream().map(service::getById).collect(Collectors.toList())`0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key attribute of Cacheable takes a SpEL expression to calculate the cache key. So you should be able to do something like

```
@Cacheable(key = "#ids.stream().map(b -> Integer.toString(b)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
```

This would require the ids to always be in the same order

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key

A better option would be to create a class to wrap around your ids that would be able to generate the cache key for you, or some kind of utility class function.

---

Another possible Solution without `@Cacheable` would be to inject the cache manager into the class like:

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;
```

You can then retrieve the food cache from the cache manager by name

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache('cache name');
```

then you could adjust your method to take in the list of ids and manually add and get the values from cache

```
cache.get(id);
cache.put(id, food);
```

You will most likely still not be able to use the SQL IN clause, but you are at least handling the iteration inside the method and not everywhere this method is called, and leveraging the cache whenever possible.

```
public List<Food> get(List<Integer> ids) {
    List<Food> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Integer id : ids) {
        // Attempt to fetch from cache
        Food food = cache.get(id);

        if (food == null) {
            // Fetch from DB
            cache.put(id, food);
        }

        result.add(food);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Relevant Javadocs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html

Comment: Thanks. But in that case the example in my question wouldn't work, because the key is not the same in both cases. I want to cache each single Food, not the whole set.

Comment: Okay in that case, if you want to use `@Cacheable` you'll need to just iterate the calls to have your method take a single id and return a single result.

Comment: Without @Cacheable, you could Inject the CacheManager and use an instance of the cache to put and get the cache values manually

Comment: Perfect! I like the cachemanager approach. Post it and I will accept